# Unity GameObject.Destroy() not working with direct reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am struggling to identify the issue with the GameObject.Destroy(destroyCell) function on a Prefab item held in a list. I have shown there is a direct reference to the object by calling destroyCell.Select() {internal function to highlight the Cell object} on it before calling Destroy and removing it from the list. The list count shows the object is removed but Destroy is not taking effect.

The general idea is to click and drag from a position with cells being added to a container object relative to dragged distance from the origin, and removing the cells as you move back to the origin.

The mechanism for adding and removing cells is shown below:

```
if (mouseDistFromOrigin < prevDragInteractFloorValue && cellsToModify.Count > 1)
{
    // REMOVE CELL
    cellsAvailableToGenerate++;
    energyAvailable += CellHelper.EnergyGainPerCell;

    nextCellYOffset /= CellHelper.NewCellGrowthRatio;
    dragInteractFloorValue = prevDragInteractFloorValue;
    prevDragInteractFloorValue -= nextCellYOffset * cellsToModify[cellsToModify.Count - 1].transform.localScale.y;

    //var containerCells = container.GetComponentsInChildren<Cell>();
    //Debug.Log("CELLS " + containerCells.Length);
    //var destroyCell = containerCells[containerCells.Length - 1];
    //GameObject.Destroy(destroyCell);
    //GameObject.Destroy(containerCells[containerCells.Length - 1]);

    Debug.Log("CELLS: " + cellsToModify.Count);

    var destroyCell = cellsToModify[cellsToModify.Count - 1];
    destroyCell.Select();
    cellsToModify.Remove(destroyCell);
    GameObject.Destroy(destroyCell);

    Debug.Log("CELLS: " + cellsToModify.Count);
} else if (mouseDistFromOrigin > dragInteractFloorValue && 
    cellsAvailableToGenerate > 0 && 
    energyAvailable >= CellHelper.EnergyGainPerCell)
    {// CAN GENERATE CELL
        prevDragInteractFloorValue = dragInteractFloorValue;
        // ADD CELL
        Cell prev = cellsToModify[cellsToModify.Count - 1];
        Vector3 top = CellHelper.TopOfCellPos(prev);

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(top.x, top.y, 0);
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);

        Debug.Log("NEW - LENGTH " + mouseDistFromOrigin +
            " FLOOR " + dragInteractFloorValue +
            " ANGLE: " + Utils.ZeroAngleDeg(angle + angleOffset) +
            " X " + pos.x +
            " Y " + pos.y);

        Cell cell = Object.Instantiate(prev, pos, rot, container.transform);
        cell.transform.localScale = CellHelper.LocalScaleFromPreviousCell(prev);
        CellHelper.SetColourByColour(cell, cellFadeColour);

        // MODIFY VALUES
        cellsAvailableToGenerate--;
        energyAvailable -= CellHelper.EnergyGainPerCell;

        nextCellYOffset *= CellHelper.NewCellGrowthRatio;
        dragInteractFloorValue += nextCellYOffset * cell.transform.localScale.y;

        cellsToModify.Add(cell);
    }
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @Tyler2P I did not realize there were indents when pasting buckets of code =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By calling  [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) (which btw is in general in the [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) class)

```
Object.Destroy(destroyCell);
```

You **only** destroy the `Cell` component itself, **not** the according `GameObject`!

> Removes a GameObject, **component** or asset.
>
> ...
>
> **If `obj` is a [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html), this method removes the component from the [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) and destroys it**. If `obj` is a [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html), it destroys the [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html), all its components and all transform children of the [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).

It should rather be

```
Object.Destroy(destroyCell.gameObject)
```

Comment: Boom!! Champion. Thank you very much.